# How to get a list of readOnly fields from a JsonSchema in Java

Tags: json, validation, field, readonly, jsonschema

I am trying to validate a JSON input against a schema using the json-schema-validator library: https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator. The validation works fine. However, one of my requirement is to make sure that the input doesn't contain any readonly fields. I have marked the fields as readonly in the json schema but there's no good way to know which fields are readonly in the java code.

Here's an example schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
  "required":false,
  "properties": {
    "partId": {
      "type": "string",
      "final":true,
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 36
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "forSaleDate": {
      "type":"string",
      "format":"date",
      "final":true,
      "readOnly":true   
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the code I used for validation:

```
JsonNode jsonSchemaNode = null;
try {
jsonSchemaNode = JsonLoader.fromString(schemaString);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
log.error("Invalid JSON schema");
throw e;
}
JsonSchema jsonSchema = factory.fromSchema(jsonSchemaNode);
JsonNode json = null;
try {
json = mapper.readTree(example);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
log.error("Invalid JSON string");
}
if (json != null) {
ValidationReport validationReport = jsonSchema.validate(json);
}
```

The last field in my schema "forSaleDate" is a readonly field. In my validation code, the JSON input will get parsed into a JsonNode and I can call the "has(fieldName)" method on that JsonNode to see if it contains a particular field. The idea is to do this for all the readonly fields. However, the tricky part is to figure out which fields are readonly. The schema in the above code is represented as JsonSchema and it does not have a method that would return all the readonly fields. Did anyone come across this sort of validation? If yes, what was your approach?